# Why is Chrome on OSX resizing the window when the autohidden menu bar is shown/hovered instead of overlapping it?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm on Mojave and Chrome 69.

When an app is in fullscreen mode and I move my mouse towards the top of the screen causing the Apple menu bar to display, it overlaps the current app for the duration that it is visible. This used to be the case for Google Chrome also.

When the menu bar is visible, it bounces down chrome's tab bar triggering a resize of the chrome app. Because of this behaviour, when I move the mouse to the top of the screen to try click on a tab, I inadvertantly end up displaying the Apple menu bar and this causes Chrome to resize and the tab bar to move down. This is a real pain.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour and go back to the older overlap behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I have Chrome 84.

This doesn't happen all the time, but I found how to reproduce that.

When I hover over menu bar, then open Spotlight search type something like pref, ti open system preferences, Chrome resizes down a bit to accommodate the menu bar. Which should not take any space. This doesn't happen with other apps, only with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

One work around this problem is

under
**System Preferences** -> **Dock & Menu Bar** 
uncheck **Automatically hide and show menu bar in full screen**
& Restart Chrome